# Local variables - switch case

Tags: c#, variables, switch-statement, local

I am studying programming and I am very beginner (started 2 months ago).
I am doing a c# exercise for maths calculation. Our professor used a if ... else (embricated) loops to do the exercise. I wanted to use a switch case but I am struggling with the local variables.

I understand the issue: case 2 and 3 does not "know" the variables totalNumber and nbrSubAssy is as they come from case 1 and case 2, then they are detected as not assigned.

If I still want to use a switch case, what could I do to solve it?

```
using System;

namespace Denombrements
{
    class Program
    {

        static long IntMultiplication(int startValue, int endValue)
        {
            long multiplication = 1;
            for (int k = startValue; k <= endValue; k++)
                multiplication *= k;
            return multiplication;
        }

        static int UserSelection(String message)
            {
                int number = 0;
                Console.Write(message);
                try
                {
                    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input, enter an integer");
                }

                return number;

            }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char choice = '1';
            while (choice != '0')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Permutation ...................... 1");
                Console.WriteLine("Arrangement ...................... 2");
                Console.WriteLine("Combination ...................... 3");
                Console.WriteLine("Quit ............................. 0");
                Console.Write("Choice :                           ");
                choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.WriteLine();

                switch(choice)
                {  
                    case '0':
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        int totalNumber = UserSelection("Total number of elements to be taken into account");
                        long permutation = IntMultiplication(1, totalNumber);
                        Console.WriteLine(totalNumber + "! = " + permutation);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        int nbrSubAssy = UserSelection("Total number of elements in the subassy to be taken into account");
                        long arrangement = IntMultiplication(totalNumber - nbrSubAssy + 1, totalNumber);
                        Console.WriteLine("A(" + totalNumber + "/" + nbrSubAssy + ") = " + arrangement);
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        long combination = arrangement / IntMultiplication(1, nbrSubAssy);
                        Console.WriteLine("C(" + totalNumber + "/" + nbrSubAssy + ") = " + combination);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question title to summarise the question you're asking. Consider the difference between "car - brake - ground - wet" vs "Why does my car take longer to brake when the ground is wet?". The latter summarises the content of the question, whereas the former is just a collection of keywords.

Comment: **In this case**, I'd simply c&p the respective lines to case 3.

Comment: Side note: `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` is bad. Really bad. use `Int.TryParse` instead, and use a loop - otherwise your method will simply return 0 whenever a user enters something that can't be parsed as an int.

Comment: Thank you @ZoharPeled for your feedback. I tke note of it and will use it now.

Comment: How did you instructor do it with `if`? It's subject to the same scoping rules as `switch`...

Comment: Hello @Fildor thank you for your feedback. What do you mean about c&p ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For your case2/case3 you need to prompt the user also to input needed variables, needed for calculation, as the statement will not run through not case1 or case2 if e.g. case3 is selected

Comment: "c&p" = "copy&paste"

Comment: Hello @CaiusJard my professor used an if ... else loops and an embrication (again an if ... else... loops after the first else). So my case 1 corresponds to her first if, my case 2 corresponds to her second if and my case 3 corresponds to her the last else.

Comment: That's clear, Matthieu. Nevertheless (and what Caius was going for is) using if/else you have the same scoping issue. So in her 3rd `else` she'd also need to get the `totalNumber` and the other one somehow.

Comment: @Fildor if I copy and paste the respective lines to case 3 I will call again the same functions right ?

Comment: _"if I copy and paste the respective lines to case 3 I will call again the same functions right ?"_ - right. That will hurt the clean coder's eye a little bit ( code duplication) but, well. You should also keep it simple. Usually, I'd try and avoid dupe code, too. But in this very small case (and apparently for an assignment) I think it's justified.

Comment: Also, if you later on change the inner workings of cases 1 or 2, you probably don't want case 3 to be affected. So, dupe code may in fact be the clean way to go, here. (Again, I am only talking about this specific case, not generally.)

Comment: `Our professor used a if ... else (embricated) loops to do the exercise.` Please show us that. And explain what the word `embricated` means.

Comment: Hello @Fildor she has previously declared it, you are right. Here her code (sorry that is in french for the Console messages http://pastebin.fr/70714 Thank you for your help

Comment: Please do not use external resources. Just add the code (the relevant part) to the question.

Comment: Hello @mjwills please, see here the code http://pastebin.fr/70714 again sorry but our teacher writes all code in french. Embricated (maybe my english is not correct) means you can have a if ... else... loops within a else. Like if {....  } else { if {...  } else {...} }

Comment: `if {.... } else { if {... } else {...} }` - mon dieu

Comment: @Fildor :D that is why I used a switch case ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your variable before `While` loop and it will keep the value of it for all the life of LOOP and you could access the old values

```
char choice = '1';
int nbrSubAssy = 0;
int totalNumber = 0;
long arrangement = 0;

while (choice != '0')
 {
     // code ...
                
      switch (choice)
      {
         case '0':
              Environment.Exit(0);
              break;
          case '1':
              totalNumber = UserSelection("Total number of elements to be taken into account");
              long permutation = IntMultiplication(1, totalNumber);
              Console.WriteLine(totalNumber + "! = " + permutation);
              break;
           case '2':
              nbrSubAssy = UserSelection("Total number of elements in the subassy to be taken into account");
              arrangement = IntMultiplication(totalNumber - nbrSubAssy + 1, totalNumber);
              Console.WriteLine("A(" + totalNumber + "/" + nbrSubAssy + ") = " + arrangement);
              break;
            case '3':
               long combination = arrangement / IntMultiplication(1, nbrSubAssy);
               Console.WriteLine("C(" + totalNumber + "/" + nbrSubAssy + ") = " + combination);
                break;
             default:
                 Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
                  break;
        }
   }
```

or in my opinion the better solution you could ask for the value in every case you need them